# Double Ended Queue structure in C. Problems

Tags: c, struct, deque

I'm trying to create dequeue structure to insert/delete first nodes, insert/delete last nodes. I've wrote everything in one .c file and it worked perfectly, but when I tried to make a project file out of it (3 files: main, header, functions), it just doesn't work. First problem I encountered after making project: printing dequeue infinite times (function `void printDeque(deque *d)`).

Here's the working one-file'd code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct dequeNode *link;
struct dequeNode{
    int data;
    link next;
};


typedef struct{
    link front;
    link rear;
}deque;


void initDeque(deque *d){ //Create new deque
    d->front=NULL;
    d->rear=NULL;
}


int isEmpty(deque *d){  //Function to find, if deque is empty
    if((d->front)==NULL){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}


void putFront(deque *d,int x){ //Function to insert data in front of deque
    link node=(link)malloc(sizeof(struct dequeNode));
    node->data=x;
    node->next=NULL;
    if(isEmpty(d)){
        node->next=d->front;
        d->front=node;
    }else{
        d->front=node;
        d->rear=node;
    }
}


void putRear(deque *d,int x){ //Function to insert data in rear of deque
    link node=(link)malloc(sizeof(struct dequeNode));
    node->data=x;
    node->next=NULL;
    if(isEmpty(d)){
        d->rear->next=node;
        d->rear=node;
    }else{
        d->front=node;
        d->rear=node;
    }
}


int getFront(deque *d){ //Delete first node of deque
    link node=d->front;
    int x=node->data;
    if((d->front)==(d->rear)){
        d->front=NULL;
        d->rear=NULL;
    }else{
        d->front=node->next;
    }
    free(node);
    return x;
}


int getRear(deque *d){ //Delete last node of deque
    link node=d->front;
    link tr=d->rear;
    int x=tr->data;
    if(node==tr){
        d->front=NULL;
        d->rear=NULL;
    }else{
        while((node->next)!=tr){
            node=node->next;
        }
        d->rear=node;
    node->next=NULL;
    }
    free(tr);
    return x;
}


void printDeque(deque *d){ //Print out deque to console
    link node=d->front;
    while(node!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",node->data);
        node=node->next;
    }
}


void main(){
    int x;
    deque *d;
    d=(deque*)malloc(sizeof(deque));
    initDeque(d);
    putFront(d,10);
    putFront(d,20);
    putRear(d,30);
    putFront(d,40);
    putRear(d,50);
    putFront(d,60);
    printf("\n");
    printDeque(d);
    if(isEmpty(d))
        x=getFront(d);
    printf("\n");
    printDeque(d);
    if(isEmpty(d))
        x=getRear(d);
    printf("\n");
    printDeque(d);
    if(isEmpty(d))
    x=getFront(d);
    printf("\n");
    printDeque(d);
}
```

Here's three files to make a project out of it:

main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"deque.h"

void main(){
    int x;
    deque *d;
    d=(deque*)malloc(sizeof(deque));
    initDeque(d);
    putFront(d,10);
    putFront(d,20);
    printDeque(d);
    putRear(d,30);
    putFront(d,40);
    putRear(d,50);
    putFront(d,60);
    printf("\n");
    printDeque(d);
    if(isEmpty(d))
        x=getFront(d);
    printf("\n");
    printDeque(d);
    if(isEmpty(d))
        x=getRear(d);
    printf("\n");
    printDeque(d);
    if(isEmpty(d))
    x=getFront(d);
    printf("\n");
    printDeque(d);
}
```

header file (deque.h):

```
#ifndef deque_H
#define deque_H
typedef struct dequeNode *link;
struct dequeNode{
    int data;
    link next;
};


typedef struct{
    link front;
    link rear;
}deque;



void initDeque(deque*);
int isEmpty(deque*);
void putFront(deque*,int);
void putRear(deque*,int);
int getFront(deque*);
int getRear(deque*);
void printDeque(deque*);


#endif
```

and function file (functions.c):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"deque.h"



void initDeque(deque *d){ //Create new deque
    d->front=NULL;
    d->rear=NULL;
}


int isEmpty(deque *d){  //Function to find, if deque is empty
    if((d->front)==NULL){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}


void putFront(deque *d,int x){ //Function to insert data in front of deque
    link node=(link)malloc(sizeof(struct dequeNode));
    node->data=x;
    node->next=NULL;
    if(isEmpty(d)){
        node->next=d->front;
        d->front=node;
    }else{
        d->front=node;
        d->rear=node;
    }
}


void putRear(deque *d,int x){ //Function to insert data in rear of deque
    link node=(link)malloc(sizeof(struct dequeNode));
    node->data=x;
    node->next=NULL;
    if(isEmpty(d)){
        d->rear->next=node;
        d->rear=node;
    }else{
        d->front=node;
        d->rear=node;
    }
}


int getFront(deque *d){ //Delete first node of deque
    link node=d->front;
    int x=node->data;
    if((d->front)==(d->rear)){
        d->front=NULL;
        d->rear=NULL;
    }else{
        d->front=node->next;
    }
    free(node);
    return x;
}


int getRear(deque *d){ //Delete last node of deque
    link node=d->front;
    link tr=d->rear;
    int x=tr->data;
    if(node==tr){
        d->front=NULL;
        d->rear=NULL;
    }else{
        while((node->next)!=tr){
            node=node->next;
        }
        d->rear=node;
    node->next=NULL;
    }
    free(tr);
    return x;
}


void printDeque(deque *d){ //Print out deque to console
    link node=d->front;
    while(node!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",node->data);
        node=node->next;
    }
}
```

Second problem: I create first node `deque *d; d=(deque*)malloc(sizeof(deque));` in `int main`, but is there a possibility to create it in, lets say `void initDeque()`?

Comment: First thing I noticed: you commented out `InitDeque` in `main`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake not deleting `//` after my last debugging the program. Edited post.

Comment: In response to the second problem: if you declare `initDeque` as `deque *initDeque(void)` then you can call `malloc` inside the function and return the pointer.

Comment: code, as posted, works just fine as three modules: returns 5 lines, with the expected results.

Comment: Thank you for fast answers guys. The problem was my computer, because as I tried it on the other PC, code works just fine. And user3386109, could you show example of that piece of code in answer section? Because I'm kinda lost in that structure.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you have - error in isEmpty() function. If NULL, you should return true, if not NULL - you should return false.

UPD. For remain the rest code unchanged, you can rename isEmpty to isNotEmpty (as supposed isedev). Also, it is worth to add check if "d" pointer is equal to NULL in this function:

```
//Function to find, if deque is not empty
int isNotEmpty(deque *d)
{
    if (!d || !d->front)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Whilst the function should probably be renamed `isNotEmpty`, there is no logic error in its use in the code.

Comment: and comment probably should be rename too? don't make me laugh

Comment: @isedev You are wrong. Pointer d can be equal to NULL. So the valid condition will be  return d == NULL || d->front==NULL;

Comment: I meant the use of `isEmpty` in the rest of the code. Changing the logic within the function as per answer would break the rest of the code. But you are right, `d` should be checked against NULL, although that is a different point.

Comment: It's a problem of semantic. When you're writing code you should care both about semantics and logics corectness.

Comment: Then at least update your answer to include the related changes the code would require. Implementing just the change you posted would break the code. As you said, semantics and *logic*...

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the problem about code not working at all. What about second question, to move `d` pointer into one of the first functions, lets say in `iniDeque`?

Comment: why not, of course you can do it, to hide implementation details from potential users of your data structure